# Counting Problem Concerning the Stars and Bars Technique

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I need to distribute $k$ indistinguishable balls to $n$ distinguishable bins.  Of course, this is plainly an example where the so-called stars-and-bars technique is helpful: this technique yields an answer of ${k+n-1 \choose n}$.  However, I cannot understand why the answer isn't simply $n^k$, since there are $n$ possibilities for the placement of $k$ balls.  Could anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: That was a typo on my part.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If **both** the $k$ balls and the $n$ bins are indistinguishable it *is not* a stars and bars problem.

The solution is $\sum_{t=1}^n p(k, t)$, where $p(k,t)$ is the number of partitions of the integer $k$ into $t$ non-empty parts.

Eg: 2 indistinct balls can be placed in 2 indistinct boxes in only $2$ ways: $**|$, $*|*$

Note: $|**$ isn't a solution when the boxes aren't distinguishable: We can't say which is the first or second.

---

The stars and bars solution, ${k+n-1\choose k}$ is for $k$ indistinguishable balls and $n$ distinct bins. ($k$ Stars and $n-1$ bars)

Eg: 2 indistinct balls can be placed in 2 distinct boxes in $3$ ways: $**|$, $*|*$, $|**$

---

$n^k$ is the solution to $k$ distinct balls and $n$ distinct bins.

Eg: 2 distinct balls can be placed in 2 distinct boxes in $4$ ways: $AB|$, $A|B$, $B|A$, $|AB$

---

For completion if we have $k$ distinct balls and $n$ indistinct bins then the solution is $\sum_{t=1}^n S(k, t)$ where $S(k, t)$ is a **Stirling Number** of the second kind.

Eg: 2 distinct balls can be placed in 2 indistinct boxes in $2$ ways: $AB|$, $A|B$

These are but four of the **Twelvefold Way**.

Answer (score 1):

It's because everything is indistinguishable.  Here's a simple example:  Say we have 3 balls and 3 bins.    Then we can have the following configations:

All 3 in 1 bin, or

2 in 1 bin,  1 in another,or

1 in 1 bin, 1 in 1 bin, 1 in a third.

So we only have 3 total possibilities here,  not $3^3$.   Now,  if each ball was different from each other ball, AND each bin was different from each other bin, then we would have $3^3$